# How to Add a column to a table the column values depends on another columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to alter my table and add a column 'mycolumn' to it. The column values depends on three columns inside the table.

For example:

```
  ID     mycolumn       col1      col2      col3
.....   ...........    ......    ......    ......
  1       1111           1         1         1
  2       1112           1         1         1
  3       1213           1         2         1
  4       1224           1         2         2
  5       2225           2         2         2
```

Comment: So you want query for insert which will concatenate the values?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: [Computed columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) will helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the column as nullable and then execute this UPDATE:

```
UPDATE dbo.MyTable 
SET mycolumn = CAST(
       CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(5)) +
       CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(5)) +
       CAST(col3 AS VARCHAR(5)) +
       CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)) AS int)
WHERE mycolumn IS NULL
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d33d7/2/0)

You could also use a computed column (persisted or not):

```
--ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
--DROP COLUMN [MyColumn]

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD [MyColumn] AS 
   ((CONVERT([nvarchar](max),col1,0))+CONVERT([nvarchar](max),col2,0)+CONVERT([nvarchar](max),col3,0)+CONVERT([nvarchar](max),[ID],0)) PERSISTED
```

Comment: this is good, but I want to add the column not update my data and after that I can add data 'mycolumn' automatically contains this value

Comment: @Khaledalmolaa: why don't you mention it in your question? Yes, you could use this code in a trigger.

Comment: I don't want use trigger

Comment: @Khaledalmolaa: you could use a computed instead of a physical column

Comment: @Khaledalmolaa: i've added the computed column approach.

Comment: My problem has solved by computed column approach that you are added, thank you.